# Stacking 3D dataset using GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

Does Grass GIS consider a 3D set as a single XY location, with a Z (elevation), and a property P.  I have a dataset with vertical data points (stacked) in XY coordinates.

Each XY location has a Z and a Property. therefore i have as many XY as P.

I am wondering if I should slice the dataset into individual elevations (one data set for each Z), so that I can import and interpolate.

Answer (score 2):

[`r3.in.xyz`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r3.in.xyz.html) can take x, y, z and, optionally, value (property *P*) columns, so you don't have to slice the data set into individual elevations.